# Using React-Router 6 every time try to navigate getting error of no route match found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

app.js

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        {BaseRoutes.map((route) => (
          <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
      <ToastContainer />
    </>
  );
};
```

routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from "./pages/Container";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import SignInScreen from "./pages/login/signInScreen/SignInScreen";
import EnterOtp from "./pages/login/enterOtp";
import SignUp from "./pages/login/signUpScreen";
import SignUpDetail from "./pages/login/signUpDetail/SignUpDetail";
import CreateNewPassword from "./pages/login/createPassword/CreateNewPassword";
import ForgotPassword from "./pages/login/forgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import LoginSuccess from "./pages/login/loginSuccess/LoginSuccess";
import Landing from "./pages/Landing";
import DetailsPage from "./pages/DetailsPage/DetailsPage";
import StaticPages from "./components/StaticPages";
import SearchPage from "./components/SearchPage";
import PlayerPage from "./pages/Player/PlayerPage";
import Favourites from "./pages/Favourites";
import SignInOtp from "./pages/login/signInOtp/SignInOtp";
import LivePage from "./pages/Player/LivePage";
import MoreSection from "./pages/MoreSection/MoreSection";
import ViewEpisodes from "./components/ViewEpisodes";

export const NextRoutes = [
  { path: "/login", element: <SignInScreen /> },
  { path: "/home", element: <Home /> },
  { path: "/loginOtp", element: <SignInOtp /> },
  { path: "/otp", element: <EnterOtp /> },
  { path: "/signup", element: <SignUp /> },
  { path: "/createPassword", element: <CreateNewPassword /> },
  { path: "/signupdetail", element: <SignUpDetail /> },
  { path: "/loginSuccess", element: <LoginSuccess /> },
  { path: "/landing", element: <Landing /> },
  { path: "/forgot", element: <ForgotPassword /> },
];

export const BaseRoutes = [
  { path: "/", element: <Container /> },
  { path: "", element: <Container /> },
];
```

This is container.js file where map through nextRoutes to create nested routes.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Route, useNavigate, useLocation, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { bindActionCreators, compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { NextRoutes } from "../../routes";
import "./index.scss";
import Splash from "../Splash";
import Home from "../Home";
import SignInScreen from "../login/signInScreen/SignInScreen";
import Loader from "../../components/Loader/Loader";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";
import SideDrawer from "../../components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer";
import Backdrop from "../../components/Backdrop/Backdrop";
import useScrollHandler from "../../helpers/useScrollHandler";
import { deleteKey, getKey } from "../../utils/storage";
import Modal from "../../components/shared/Modal";
import { general, logout_constants } from "../../constants/constants";
import { routeConstants } from "../../constants/routeConstants";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { isAuthenticatedUtil } from "../../utils/authUtils";

const Container = (props) => {
  const [sideDrawerOpen, setSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const menuDataList = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.menuDataList) || [];
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const isLoader = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.isLoader);
  const signInResponse = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.signInResponse);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isAuth = isAuthenticatedUtil(signInResponse);
    setIsAuthenticated(isAuth);
  }, [signInResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContentRightInfo());
  }, []);

  const drawerToggleHandler = () => {
    setSideDrawerOpen(!sideDrawerOpen);
  };

  const backDropClickHandler = () => {
    setSideDrawerOpen(false);
  };

  const handleScroll = (scrollTop) => {
    setIsScrolled(scrollTop > 0);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // don't use document for selectors use referer which has been already declared
    if (document) {
      const ele = document.querySelector(".home-container");
      if (ele) {
        ele.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    }

    return () => {};
  }, []);

  const onSignOutClick = () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      setOpenModal(true);
    } else {
      //history.push(`${routeConstants.LOGIN}`);
    }
  };

  const onSignOut = () => {
    closeModal();
    logout();
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    dispatch(setLoader());

    try {
      await dispatch(
        logoutUser(
          getKey("jwt_token"),
          async (res) => {
            deleteKey([
              "jwt_token",
              "refresh_token",
              "subscriber_info",
              "subscriber_email",
              "recentSearch",
              "subscriber_full_info",
            ]);

            await dispatch({
              type: authConstants.LOGOUT,
            });

            //toast.success(res.message);
            dispatch(removeLoader());
            //history.push(`${routeConstants.LOGIN}`);
          },
          (e) => {
            toast.error(e.message);
            dispatch(removeLoader());
          }
        )
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Logout error:", error);
      dispatch(removeLoader());
    }
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (menuDataList?.length) {
  //     const isAuth = isAuthenticatedUtil(signInResponse);
  //     setIsAuthenticated(isAuth);
  //     if (isAuth && history.location.pathname == "/") {
  //       handleSkipPassword();
  //     }
  //   }
  // }, [menuDataList?.length, history.location.pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchConfigId());

    dispatch(fetchMenuDataListByPlatform("IS_WEB"));
  }, []);

  const handleSkipPassword = () => {
    const itemData = menuDataList?.find((ele) => ele.tabName === "Home");
    const pageid = itemData?.linkToPage;
    //history.push(`${routeConstants.CATEGORY}/${pageid}/${itemData?.tabName}`);
  };

  const refer = useScrollHandler(handleScroll);

  return (
    <div className="home-container" ref={refer}>
      {isLoader ? <Loader /> : null}
      {!location.pathname.includes(general.VIDEO) && (
        <>
          <Header
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            drawerClickHandler={drawerToggleHandler}
            isScrolled={isScrolled}
            closeModal={closeModal}
            onSignOutClick={onSignOutClick}
          />
          <SideDrawer
            listItemClick={backDropClickHandler}
            show={sideDrawerOpen}
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            closeModal={closeModal}
            onSignOutClick={onSignOutClick}
          />
          {sideDrawerOpen && <Backdrop click={backDropClickHandler} />}
        </>
      )}
      <Routes>
        {NextRoutes.map((route) => {
          console.log(route,'hgh');
          return (
            <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
          );
        })}
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={props?.splash?.splash ? <Splash /> : <SignInScreen />}
        />
      </Routes>
      <Outlet />
      {openModal && (
        <Modal
          show={openModal}
          handleClose={closeModal}
          buttonLabel={logout_constants.SIGN_OUT}
          buttonClick={onSignOut}
        >
          <p className="modal_text">{logout_constants.SIGN_OUT_TEXT}</p>
        </Modal>
      )}
      {openModal && <Backdrop click={closeModal} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  splash: state.splash,
  isLoader: state.isLoader,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);
};

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(Container);
```

Now whenever I try to navigate for example `useNavigate('/login')`, it gives me error of no route match found. What is an issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`app.js` renders the `BaseRoutes` routes, and `BaseRoutes` renders `Container` on route path `"/"`. `Container` then renders ***descendent*** routes which include the `NextRoutes` routes. These descendent routes are not reachable because `Container` is rendered only when the path ***exactly*** matches `"/"`.

If you would like to match and render descendent routes then append the wildcard matcher, or [splat](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats), `"*"` character to the parent path.

```
export const BaseRoutes = [
  { path: "/*", element: <Container /> },
];
```

The following would also work, just a "catch-all" route that renders `Container`.

```
export const BaseRoutes = [
  { path: "*", element: <Container /> },
];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, now it works fine when I navigate. But when i reload the page it still gives "Cannot GET /login".

Comment: @manumehra This sounds like the server or hosting service serving your application needs to be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into your app. If you need help with this new issue then please create a new post and include where & how you are deploying/hosting/serving your application. Feel free to ping me again here with a link to it and I can take a look when available. In the meantime, has the answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your question/issue from this post?